# "Log In With PayPal" fails with connection reset?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, paypal-sandbox, passport.js

I have been attempting to use the [passport-oauth2](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth2) module to use the [Log In With Paypal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/log-in-with-paypal/) service. At this point, I'm only working with the sandbox and not production (yet).

I am successfully using the [passport-google-oauth](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth) and [passport-amazon](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-amazon) to authenticate with each of those services via oauth2.  Given this, I'm confused about what I'm doing wrong with PayPal.

With PayPal, I can't get the sandbox to work at all. I get a login screen that takes credentials, but after entering them I am getting a connection reset error every time.  I have tried logging out of all PayPal sessions, closing browsers, etc.  Despite my client-side fiddling, I never make it back from PayPal to my callback.

So...to the code!

I have a configuration object for development:

```
"paypal" : {
    "clientID": "copied from the developer My REST Apps test credentials",
    "clientSecret" : "more copied test credentials",
    "callbackURL" : "https://localhost/auth/paypal/cb",
    "authorizationURL": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/auth/protocol/openidconnect/v1/authorize",
    "tokenURL": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/tokenservice"
}
```

And I have a little library that does this:

```
var PayPalStrategy = require('paypal-oauth2').Strategy;
exports.paypalStrategy = function (conf) {
    // 'conf' is the configuration from the first code block
    return new PaypalStrategy({
            clientID: conf.clientID,
            clientSecret: conf.clientSecret,
            callbackURL: conf.callbackURL,
            authorizationURL : conf.authorizationURL,
            tokenURL: conf.tokenURL
        },
        function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
          // we never get here because our connection is reset.           
        });
};
```

And my routes are simple:

```
app.get('/auth/paypal',
    passport.authenticate('oauth2', {scope: 'profile'}),
    function (req, res) {}
);

app.get('/auth/paypal/cb',
    passport.authenticate('oauth2', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
    function (req, res) {
        res.redirect('/profile');
    });
```

My guess is that I'm (a) getting something wrong with the endpoints or (b) I'm missing some step with the test account configuration on PayPal's dev site.  Sadly, I can't seem to find what I need in the docs.  Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: have you opened the necessary ports on the client side for incoming requests? I will be trying this in next some days..will let you know if I get it..also I found a useful git repo https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-paypal/tree/master/examples/signon

Comment: Which ports are you talking about?  Also, the passport-paypal module uses OpenID and not OAuth...and the [passport-paypal-oauth](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-paypal-oauth) module has some issues that prevent it from working.  These were reasons I went with the straight OAuth module instead of one written for paypal.

Comment: Oh ok..i just meant opening the firewall for incoming connections on the port that your app is running on..quite basic..but i hadn't done that when i was trying something else (expresscheckout) and then the connection would reset..

Comment: I have tried login with PayPal using the dynamic builder form https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/identity/button-js-builder/ ..for me it depends on the network i am in..at home it works in both browsers..but at my work network it works in chrome but not in firefox (I get the same connection reset error as u)..so i am assuming there is some firewall or proxy blocking it..

Answer (score 0):

Mine worked with the following:

1) Clear browser cache and history.

2) Delete cookies.

And try again.

Comment: Tried!  Unsuccessful as a fix.  I tried resetting Chrome and even opened other browsers that never get used.  I must have something wrong someplace else.  If I figure it out (I've parked this on a ToDo list) I'll come back and update for posterity.  :(

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours I mucking around with passport, I ended up moving towards using the node-palpal-sdk instead. I think what makes it confusing is how paypals oauth flows talk about openid on the endpoints urls. Here's a gist of how I got it working, straight forward after you put the pieces together:

https://gist.github.com/jkresner/8a581e50dcac58edbd10